# How to declare instance of another class in one class

Tags: c++, arduino

I am a beginner and writing a class in c++ for arduino. I need help with using one class in my class. Code below.

## MyClass.h:

```
class MyClass {

  public:
    boolean initialize();
  private:
    std::unique_ptr<DHT> dht; // works
    std::unique_ptr<LiquidCrystal_I2C> lcd(0x3F, 16, 2); //  error: expected identifier before numeric constant

}
```

## MyClass.cpp:

```
#include "WifiConfig.h"
WifiConfig::WifiConfig() {}

boolean MyClass::initialize(){
      lcd->begin(); // invalid use of member function (did you forget the '()' ?)
   }
```

How can i declare instance of another class which requires params in constructor.

Comment: Please post the full compiler error. You are missing a semicolon after `begin()`. And member variables are initialized inside the constructor. In-place initialization is not allowed for user-defined members. Also `boolean` is not valid C++ type, use `bool`

Comment: I don't know the ctor of `LiquidCrystal_I2C`, but you have to use `new` for your `std::unique_ptr` -> `std::unique_ptr<LiquidCrystal_I2C> lcd(new LiquidCrystal_I2C(0x3F, 16, 2)); //  error: expected identifier before numeric constant`

Comment: Look up how to construct an [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr#Example). `std::unique_ptr<LiquidCrystal_I2C> lcd(0x3F, 16, 2);` is not how to do it.

Comment: ideally you should provide memory to your unique_ptr in constructor

Comment: @skratchi.at i tried that, `error: expected identifier before 'new'`

Comment: @Quimby fixed. This is arduino code.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude can you help me with sample code. i am a total noob.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When doing inline iniitalization of a class member variable, you either need to use curly-braces `{}`:

```
std::unique_ptr<LiquidCrystal_I2C> lcd{new LiquidCrystal_I2C(0x3F, 16, 2)};
```

Or "assignment" syntax with `=`:

```
std::unique_ptr<LiquidCrystal_I2C> lcd = new LiquidCrystal_I2C(0x3F, 16, 2);
```

Or do your initialization in the constructor, as part of the constructor initializer list.

```
MyClass::MyClass()
    : lcd{new LiquidCrystal_I2C(0x3F, 16, 2)}
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but i got `'make_unique' is not a member of 'std'`  as i am working on arduino code.

Comment: you need to have c++ 14 compiler for that, you can use `new` instead

Comment: @VishK Updated to use `new`.